# Tomcat server is not starting as service: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

My tomcat server is working fine in Eclipse but when I try to start the server it is not starting.

Here are the errors:

```
[2012-08-15 09:26:09] [info] Procrun (2.0.5.0) started
[2012-08-15 09:26:09] [info] Running Service...
[2012-08-15 09:26:09] [info] Starting service...
[2012-08-15 09:26:09] [197  javajni.c] [error] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2012-08-15 09:26:09] [994  prunsrv.c] [error] Failed creating java C:\java\java\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2012-08-15 09:26:09] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 1
[2012-08-15 09:26:09] [info] Run service finished.
[2012-08-15 09:26:09] [info] Procrun finished.
[2012-08-15 09:29:06] [info] Procrun (2.0.5.0) started
[2012-08-15 09:29:06] [info] Running Service...
[2012-08-15 09:29:06] [info] Starting service...
[2012-08-15 09:29:06] [197  javajni.c] [error] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2012-08-15 09:29:06] [994  prunsrv.c] [error] Failed creating java C:\java\java\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2012-08-15 09:29:06] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 1
[2012-08-15 09:29:06] [info] Run service finished.
[2012-08-15 09:29:06] [info] Procrun finished.
[2012-08-15 09:30:07] [info] Procrun (2.0.5.0) started
[2012-08-15 09:30:07] [info] Running Service...
[2012-08-15 09:30:07] [info] Starting service...
[2012-08-15 09:30:07] [197  javajni.c] [error] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2012-08-15 09:30:07] [994  prunsrv.c] [error] Failed creating java C:\java\java\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2012-08-15 09:30:07] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 1
[2012-08-15 09:30:07] [info] Run service finished.
[2012-08-15 09:30:07] [info] Procrun finished.
[2012-08-15 09:30:57] [info] Procrun (2.0.5.0) started
[2012-08-15 09:30:57] [info] Running Service...
[2012-08-15 09:30:57] [info] Starting service...
[2012-08-15 09:30:57] [197  javajni.c] [error] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[2012-08-15 09:30:57] [994  prunsrv.c] [error] Failed creating java C:\java\java\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2012-08-15 09:30:57] [1269 prunsrv.c] [error] ServiceStart returned 1
[2012-08-15 09:30:57] [info] Run service finished.
[2012-08-15 09:30:57] [info] Procrun finished.
```

What does these errors mean and how do I fix them?

Comment: Can you post the error log if one exist

Comment: please check . . . i edited the post with the error

Comment: Are you running a 64bit of 32?
http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/Tomcat-6-0-12-in-windows-vista-64-bits-does-not-start-td2167434.html

Comment: yes your were right ... i uninstalled it and installed new one 64 bit version thanks for your help

Answer (score 15):

I had the exact same problem and it was caused by running a 32 bits Tomcat on a 64 bits windows. (I was using XAMPP 1.8.3 in a Windows 8 64 bits.)

First:

- Make sure you have `JAVA_HOME` system variable pointing to your jdk folder (not the `\bin`);
- Make sure `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` is in your `%PATH%` system variable.

The solution:

- Uninstall the Tomcat7 service if you have installed it already;
- Download a **64 bit version** of Tomcat 7 for windows (check [this link to get the latest](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgihttp://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) - I used the [7.0.42](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.42/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.42-windows-x64.zip) version);
- **Replace** the **`tomcat7.exe`** and **`tomcat7w.exe`** files of the `C:\xampp\tomcat\bin` folder with those present in the recently downloaded zip file.

Now you can install the service as usual (through XAMPP control panel, if you use it) and it should start just fine.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the path of 'jvm.dll' (tab 'Java' when starting tomcat8w.exe) locates the right Java Runtime Environment version (x64 or x86).

This problem occurs in both cases below :

1 - Your Tomcat server version is 64-bit but using a 32-bit version of the Java Virtual Machine.
 2 - Your Tomcat server version is 32-bit but using a 64-bit version of the Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: you should put the last line on top

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Copy msvcr71.dll from java’s bin directory to tomcat’s bin folder.

Add java’s bin directory to windows environment variable.

Copy msvcr71.dll from java’s bin directory to windows\system32 folder.

Make sure your tomcat’s pointing to correct jvm.dll folder.

Apache Tomcat[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/252I1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem occurs when

> - 64 bit Tomcat 7
> - 64 bit Windows Server
> - 32 bit JDK (in JDK_HOME system variable)

You can use 32 bit JDK only on 32 bit Tomcat 7. If you want to change Tomcat 7 64 bit to 32 bit

> - Change CATALINA_HOME variable to 32 bit Tomcat 7 path
> - Remove Tomcat Windows Service
> - Install Tomcat Windows Service

Answer (score 1):

Your Tomcat is 64 bit but pointing to a 32 bit java

1. Open Apache Tomcat configuration (from commandline: tomcat7w //ES//your-instance)
2. Go to the Java tab
3. Set the Java Virtual Machine to your desired bit-version, for instance :C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\server\jvm.dll

To avoid issues when creating new instances, check where your JAVA_HOME is pointing and set it to a 64 bit version jdk (not jre), for instance C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **run Tomcat as a Windows Service** the easiest way is to use the  [**32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer**](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi).

I had the same issue using Tomcat `service.bat install` and I had no idea if it was a 32 or 64 bit installation.

Using the Tomcat 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer helped me solved it quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Open Apache Tomcat configuration -> Java Tab -> Clic on "use default"

Answer (score 0):

Error Genrating Report on Sage CRM 7.1g: This error indicates Tomcat has stopped and cannot start. So the solution below is for both Sage CRM users who retrieve reports in excel or PDF or any other format and requires Tomcat to be running. The solution is for Tomcat6.

1. Run jdk-8u121 -windows-i586  (This is a 32 bit JDK)
2. Configure Environment Variables
   Variable Name: JAVA_HOME
   Variable value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
3. Click ok, ok, ok

4.Open registry by clicking;
   Window's Start Button ---> Type "REGEDIT" inside where it reads (Search programs and files),

Click on REGEDIT that appears

5. In registry, follow this path

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE --> SOFTWARE ----> Wow6432Node ---> Apache Software Foundation

   Collapse the elipses from "Procrun --> Tomcat6 --> Parameters
   Under Parameters you will see the following folders;

   Java
   Log
   Start
   Stop

Clickthe "Java" folder and double click Jvm under "Name" column

A pop-up box will open.

Copy the Environmental Variable Value that you set up earlier.. In this case: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
and paste inside the "Value Data" space with the \jvm.dll appended at the end.

This is the complete path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll

Close Registry and voila.

Dave