# Xampp Tomcat service (is not a valid win32)

Tags: java, windows, apache, tomcat, xampp

I've read many topics such as [Tomcat server is not starting as service: %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963994/tomcat-server-is-not-starting-as-service-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application) or [Tomcat 7 won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287659/tomcat-7-wont-start)
But it did not worked for me.

First of all I'm running Windows Server 64bits. I performed the following steps:

1. Downloaded Xampp (I believe it's 64bits..because I couldn't find a
   64 bits in their website)
2. Download JDK 8.20 x64 bits
3. Since I was in doubt about the Tomcat in Xampp, I've download the Tomcat x64 and replace the whole content in the c:\xampp\tomcat\

[image]

After everything is installed I needed to update the Environment Variables, and so I did.
[image]

After completed this steps I installed successfully the Tomcat Service, although it gives error when starting. I found the logs of the errors I and get the following:

```
[info]  [ 5096] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 32-bit) started
[info]  [ 5096] Running 'Tomcat7' Service...
[info]  [ 4876] Starting service...
[error] [ 4876] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[error] [ 4876] Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\server\jvm.dll
[error] [ 4876] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[error] [ 4876] ServiceStart returned 1
[error] [ 4876] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
[info]  [ 5096] Run service finished.
[info]  [ 5096] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

So I check if the file jvm.dll existed in that folder (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\server\jvm.dll`), but I found that it does not. I searched a little more and I found that file is actually in the folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin\server\jvm.dll`!

I then open Tomcat7 at C:\xampp\tomcat\bin and changed the path to the correct one.
[image]

But still, I keep getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

So, I had to do two steps.

1. [Download jre-7u67-windows-x64.exe](http://sdlc-esd.sun.com/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u67-b01/jre-7u67-windows-x64.exe?AuthParam=1409652913_88e73015a849cc8407618201c83eb8e7&GroupName=JSC&FilePath=/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u67-b01/jre-7u67-windows-x64.exe&File=jre-7u67-windows-x64.exe&BHost=javadl.sun.com)
2. Select, in the Tomcat7, in the tab "Java", the option "Use Default".

After that I was able to start the service properly. Plus, I've changed the port of tomcat in xampp, since by default is 8080, I changed to 9000 and I can now enter the project by localhost:9000/myproject